# CreateDialog Failed, but why GetLastError returns 0?

Tags: c++, dialog, scintilla, win32gui, comctl32

I am writing an editor for my project by using [scintilla editor component](http://www.scintilla.org/). The editor is for an internal scripting language, having all the basic functionalities like cut,copy, paste etc. As one of the feature I am also providing searching functionality. When a user presses the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> ideally it should show this dialog:

[image: Search]

But because of some reason **CreateDialog API is failing, but the GetLastError returns 0.** Also please note that I am using **Windows Common Controls**.

**>>Code for creating dialog**

```
HWND CreateFindDialog(HINSTANCE hInstance, HWND hWnd, UINT id)
{
    HWND dlgHwnd = ::CreateDialog(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(id), hWnd, FindDlgProc);
    if(dlgHwnd == NULL)
    {
        wchar_t buf [100];
        wsprintf (buf, L"Error x%x", GetLastError ());
        MessageBox (0, buf, L"CreateDialog", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
    }

    return(dlgHwnd);
}

BOOL CALLBACK FindDlgProc(HWND hWndDlg, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(Msg)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        MessageBox (0, L"in", L"CreateDialog", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch(wParam)
        {
        case IDOK:
            EndDialog(hWndDlg, 0);
            return TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

**>>Resource entry for the dialog**

```
IDD_FIND DIALOGEX 0, 0, 304, 90
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | DS_CENTER | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Find Text"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    LTEXT           "Search String",IDC_STATIC,7,7,44,8
    EDITTEXT        IDC_FIND_TEXT,7,20,217,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "Find Next",IDC_FIND_NEXT,243,7,54,16,WS_DISABLED
    PUSHBUTTON      "Find Previous",IDC_FIND_PREVIOUS,243,26,54,16,WS_DISABLED
    PUSHBUTTON      "Close",IDCANCEL,243,45,54,16
    CONTROL         "Match case",IDC_FIND_CASE,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_TABSTOP,7,42,52,10
    CONTROL         "Match whole word",IDC_FIND_WHOLE,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_TABSTOP,7,55,74,10
    CONTROL         "Wrap around",IDC_FIND_WRAP,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_TABSTOP,116,42,58,10
    CONTROL         "<a>Goto Replace (Ctrl+H)</a>",IDC_FIND_OPENREPLACE,
                    "SysLink",WS_TABSTOP,218,70,79,13
END
```

The only page talking about the same problem is this: [CreateDialog Failed, but GetLastError return 0](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=367761). I have checked the solution mentioned there but in my project I am linking to  **comctl32.lib**. I have also checked my resource file and the resource header. The dialog entry seems to be proper.

---

**>>Common control initialization**

```
 INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX iccx;
 iccx.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
 iccx.dwICC = ICC_WIN95_CLASSES|ICC_COOL_CLASSES|ICC_BAR_CLASSES|ICC_USEREX_CLASSES;
 if (!InitCommonControlsEx(&iccx))
    return;
```

Any suggestion/idea would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: how did you initialize comctl32? Which version did you manifest?

Comment: I ask because [SysLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760706(v=vs.85).aspx) requires v6 comctl32.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Please see my updated answer. If it helps, I am using windows vista withs service pack 1, visual studio 2008 and latest release of scintilla. thanks.

Comment: which comctl32 version? Do you have the v6 app manifest?

Comment: @David Heffernan: Sorry i didn't answer your question earlier. My app is picking up comctl version 5.82. I have used this small code snippet to find it out http://www.davekb.com/browse_programming_tips:get_version_of_comctl32_dll:txt

Comment: @David Heffernan: Oh. I get it now :). Thanks. After removing the `SysLink` it is working fine. Could you please suggest how to use the `comctl` 6.0 version. Also, please put it as answer. I will mark it accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SysLink control requires v6 of comctl32 as explained by the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760706%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You are linking to v5 comctl32 and I suspect this is the cause of your error. You need to include the [v6 comctl32 application manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).